# dynamic coloring of progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a table with bootstrap progress styles, In which I am having a dynamic table which is having a column named Rank which contains several  values starts from 1 to 100 and by using jquery and bootstrap I have convert the values  into progress bar like as shown in the fiddle. Th code is working fine but the issue is with the color, currently It will show all in blue, actually I want different colors based on progress count values say 10 - yellow, 20 -blue, 35 - red etc, duplicates color should occur only for the same value, otherwise different color. color can be dynamic

My code is as given below

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1c9exLq/)**

```
$("#table").children("tbody").children("tr").each(function (i) {
    var col = $(this).children("td.value");
    console.log(col.html());
    var pro = '<div id="left"><div class="progress" id="percentage"><div class="progress-bar" style="display: block; float: right;width: ' + col.html() + '%;"></div></div></div><div id="right">&nbsp;' + col.html() + '</div>';
    col.html(pro);
});
```

Can anyone please tell me some solutions for this

Comment: try to create a array values with color and compare array value and get colored dynamically

Comment: if that is the case I need to create array of 100 colors right

Comment: yes bro you need to create a array of 100 colors in this case. I think so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Check this demo : http://jsfiddle.net/k1c9exLq/3/

Create an array of 100 items with different dynamic color codes first, then use them back based on your rank.

#### JQUERY

```
var genCol = [];
for (var i=0; i<=100; i++)
    genCol.push('#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16));

$("#table").children("tbody").children("tr").each(function (i) {
    var col = $(this).children("td.value");
    
    var pro = '<div id="left"><div class="progress" id="percentage"><div class="progress-bar" style="display:block; float:right; width:'+col.html()+ '%;background:'+genCol[col.html()]+'"></div></div></div><div id="right">&nbsp;' + col.html() + '</div>';
    
    col.html(pro);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Click Here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_progressbar6&stacked=h)

#### HTML

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:40%">
    Free Space
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" style="width:10%">
    Warning
  </div>
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" style="width:20%">
    Danger
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp)

Comment: this cant be applied since say I am having 100 rows and all the progress bar should be having dynamic colors

Comment: only four colors supported for bootstrap progress such as `.progress-bar-success
.progress-bar-info
.progress-bar-warning
.progress-bar-danger`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if` statement within your Jquery code.

`if(col > 10)
{
 $('.progressbar').css('background', 'yellow');
}`

And so on.

Comment: @Aksahy how can we give dynamic coloring based on the 1-100 values, value 1 color should not be same as value 2

Comment: Okay, I didn't get that part. Give me a moment.

Comment: This cannot be achieved directly. 
You can try this out:

`var red = 0;
 var green = 0;
 var blue = 0;

 $(.progressbar).css('background', 'rgb(' + col*red + ', ' + col*green + ', ' + col*blue + ')');`

You can change the value of red green and blue as you want. 

Assuming col changes dynamically, the background color of progress bar will also change dynamically.